# How to get Custom Selected Options details from Cart in Magento2 GraphQl Query?

Tags: magento2, api, graphql

I wanted to get product custom selected options values and labels etc with Query how can i get this ?

This Query gets all the available options and selections but how can i get the selected

```
{
  customerCart {
    id
    email
    items {
      id
      quantity
      product {
        id
        sku
        name
        __typename
        ... on CustomizableProductInterface {
          options {
            uid
            title
            required
            sort_order
            option_id
            ... on CustomizableDropDownOption {
              value {
                option_type_id
                price
                price_type
                sku
                sort_order
                title
              }
            }
            ... on CustomizableRadioOption {
              value {
                option_type_id
                price
                price_type
                sku
                sort_order
                title
              }
            }
            ... on CustomizableCheckboxOption {
              value {
                option_type_id
                price
                price_type
                sku
                sort_order
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check the below answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/370185/82670

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to fetch Custom Selected Options **value** and **label** of  **Simple** and **Configurable** type of products.

```
{
    customerCart {
      id
      email
      items {
        id
        quantity
        ... on SimpleCartItem {
          customizable_options {
            label
            values {
              label
              value
            }
          }
        }
        ... on ConfigurableCartItem {
          configurable_options {
            option_label
            value_label
          }
          customizable_options {
            label
            values {
              label
              value
            }
          }
        }
        ... on DownloadableCartItem {
          customizable_options {
            label
            values {
              value
              price {
                value
                units
              }
            }
          }
          links {
            title
            sample_url
            price
          }
        }
        product {
          id
          sku
          name
          __typename
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I want to get the options of downloadable products like the selected link etc

Comment: @SyedHassanZamir Updated the query. Please review and Accept answer if works

Answer (score 0):

> **Please Try Below Query**

```
{
  cart(cart_id: "82R4S0kC5PWxDXyZ6KtwG8BWGqueQQFj") {
    total_quantity
    items {
      id
      quantity
      ... on ConfigurableCartItem {
        customizable_options {
          label
          values {
            value
          }
        }
        configurable_options {
          id
          option_label
          value_id
          value_label
        }
      }
      ... on SimpleCartItem {
        customizable_options {
          label
          values {
            value
          }
        }
      }
      ... on BundleCartItem {
        bundle_options {
          label
          values {
            label
            quantity
          }
        }
      }
      ... on DownloadableCartItem {
        links {
          title
          price
        }
      }
      ... on VirtualCartItem{
        customizable_options{
          label
          values {
            label
            value
          }
        }
      }
      product {
        name
        sku
        image {
          url
          label
          position
        }
        price_tiers {
          quantity
          final_price {
            value
          }
          discount {
            amount_off
            percent_off
          }
        }
      }
      prices {
        price {
          currency
          value
        }
        row_total{
          currency
          value
        }
        row_total_including_tax{
          currency
          value
        }
        discounts{
          label
          amount {
            currency
            value
          }
        }
        total_item_discount{
          currency
          value
        }
      }
    }
    prices {
      applied_taxes {
        label
        amount {
          value
        }
      }
      discounts {
        label
        amount {
          value
        }
      }
      subtotal_including_tax{
        currency
        value
      }
      subtotal_excluding_tax {
        value
      }
      subtotal_with_discount_excluding_tax{
        currency
        value
      }
      grand_total{
        currency
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```